# Create a help click function jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a help function on a site.

I have a button (help). Once the user clicks on that button, a listener listens to where the user clicks next on the page and I want that elements info to be extracted.

I can use this information then to search on another site.

New to jquery and javascript have this so far , not sure how to continue or change

```
$("#help" ).on( "click", function() {
     alert( $( this ).text() );
});
$( "#help").trigger( "click" );
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: you want the value of the button? `$(this).val()`

Comment: Please read your question, at least me, I don't understand any..

Comment: Hi well , i have a button (help) . once the user clicks on that button the Dom should listen to where the user clicks next on the page and i want that elements info . Not sure if its more clear , as well English is not my First language so please excuse.

Comment: Just a note on what i tried to accomplish was similar to the element click on Chrome . But should have gone to the Help Page with certain parts of that element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach if you have fewer elements for which you want this functionality.

You can keep a local variable say blIsHelpActivated that gets true / false on click of your help button. When help button is activated you can set that variable to true, when its inactivated then you can set it to false.

Now you can attach on click event of controls on your page. In that you will need to check that variable and do the searching part if its value is true.

```
var blIsHelpActivated = false;

$("#help").on("click", function() {
    // Toggle boolean to identify whether help is activated or not.
    if(blIsHelpActivated)
    {
      blIsHelpActivated = false;
    }
    else
    {
      blIsHelpActivated = true;
    }
 });

 // Code to attach click event on elements.
 $("#yourelementid").on("click", function() {
    if(blIsHelpActivated)
    {
      // Your serarching code goes here.
    }
});
```

Altervatively, you can apply a common single class to each elements and you can use below code,
instead of attaching click event to each elements.

```
 // Code to handle click event on elements.
 $(".yourcommonclassname").on("click", function() {
    if(blIsHelpActivated)
    {
      // Fetch current clicked element, by using $(this)
      // And further search based on your logic.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , Unfortunately i require this to work with most elements dynamically since this will spread over multiple pages.

Comment: I have updated the answer to use another class based approach. Please read that that will be helpful to you. Applying class to searchable elements wont be a problem.

Comment: Accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you some hint on how to go about this, but you will have to learn the js/jquery to do this:

1. On click of the help button bind an onclick event handler to the body tag.
2. When a click is detected, find the target element, and get the text of the target element. (Maybe prevent default if you don't want other actions to take place).
3. Call the search using this text (ajax maybe if thats what you are planning to use).
4. Unbind the click event handler from the body if you want this action to be bound only once. Or provide a button that does this unbind for you.

Please note, if your element is a paragraph that could mean a lot of info.

Hope this helps.